# Increase Isolated storage quota programmatically

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

I create silverlight application and I used isolated storage for storing data locally.But it only provide 1 MB quota initially. I want to increase isolated storage quota programatically. I found a solution

```
public void IncreaseQuota_OnClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

{

```
try
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        // Request 5MB more space in bytes.
        Int64 spaceToAdd = 5242880;
        Int64 curAvail = store.AvailableFreeSpace;

        if (curAvail < spaceToAdd)
        {

            // Request more quota space.
            if (!store.IncreaseQuotaTo(store.Quota + spaceToAdd))
            {
                // The user clicked NO to the
                // host's prompt to approve the quota increase.
            }
            else
            {
                // The user clicked YES to the
                // host's prompt to approve the quota increase.
            }
        }
    }
}

catch (IsolatedStorageException)
{     

}
```

}

When i write this code in simple method other than user-initiated event then it not work. Please tell me how i increase isolated storage quota.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security consideration:

"This method is called when the IsolatedStorageFile.IncreaseQuotaTo method has been called to increase the isolated storage quota. "

"CheckSecuritySettings should take into account the possibility of denial-of-service attacks. For example, it should prompt the user only if the method is called from a user-initiated 
event such as a button click."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainmanager.checksecuritysettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can request a trusted application authority.